# Its normal this warning in Rails 4 install on Ubuntu 12.04 x64?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, zsh, oh-my-zsh

When I execute this command:

```
➜  ~  gem install rails
```

I get a lot warnings: [Rails 4.0 warnings](https://gist.github.com/patrickmaciel/6665160)

It's normal? (I'm starting now with Rails, so... I'm "newbie")

---

- Ubuntu 12.04 x64
- Shell: oh-my-zsh 4.3.17
- Ruby version: 2.0....
- Rails version: 4.0....

Comment: No, this is not normal.

Comment: hahahaha, yes. So? You have this problem? anyone have this? Is a bug? Or a problem with my installation? `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an RDoc bug --> https://github.com/rdoc/rdoc/issues/189

Try updating RDoc: `gem install rdoc`

Alternatively, you can skip installing the documentation, since it's available online:

`gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc`